# Get IPv6 addresses in linux using ioctl

Tags: c, linux, ipv6, ioctl

I trying to get IPv6 addresses in my linux OS like following:

```
sd = Socket_m(AF_INET6_m, SOCK_DGRAM_m, 0);

ifc.ifc_buf = buffer_p;
ifc.ifc_len = buffSize;
Ioctl_m(sd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc);
```

It works succesfully if any IPv4 address are configured for interface, but if interface has only one IPv6 address it is not returned by ioctl.

For example, I unable to get IPv6 address of the followith interface because only IPv6 address is configured:

```
br1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:18:2D:BB:34  
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:18ff:fe2d:be54/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:194244850 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72005 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12331900995 (11760.6 Mb)  TX bytes:6192406 (5.9 Mb)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that ioctl is legacy and won't return IPv6. Each platform has a different way of getting the IPv6 ones:

- Linux, use NETLINK if you're crazy, use `getifaddrs` if you have a vaguely recent glibc, otherwise read `/proc/net/if_inet6` (eg on Android).
- Darwin or FreeBSD: use `getifaddrs`.
- Solaris, use `SIOCGLIFCONF`.
- AIX, use `SIOCGIFCONF` which actually returns IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (because they have an `sa_len` field in `struct sockaddr` they can actually support that).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifation, could you please help me with understanding "/proc/net/if_inet6" format, how I can determine UP and non-loopback addresses? I read http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/proc-net.html but it is not clear..

Comment: The docs are fairly clear - it's the "interface flags" you're after. See the values in your system headers ("if.h") for `IFF_LOOPBACK` and `IFF_UP`. If you're trying to parse if_inet6 using shell, you can extract the right field using awk and AND it with the relevant constant using `&`.

Answer (score 5):

> *Get IPv6 addresses in linux using ioctl*

This probably won't work.

From [`man 7 netdevice`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html):

> **SIOCGIFCONF**
>
> Return a list of interface (transport layer) addresses.   This
>                 currently  means  only  addresses of the **AF_INET** (IPv4) family
>                 for compatibility.
>
> [...]
>
> **NOTES**
>
> [...]
>
> Local  IPv6  IP  addresses  can  be  found  via  /proc/net   or   via
>          rtnetlink(7).

Comment: I can't use routing sockets as proposed by Nicholas Wilson, I need a LSB compatible way, but seens it is a not possible?

Comment: @Unmanner: If you need to known the address to which a socket is bound locally use `getsockname()`. If you need to find out all local interfaces' addresses use `getifaddrs()` or read out `/proc/net/if_inet6` as proposed by *Nicholas Wilson* in his answer.