# Getting IP version 6 using C

Tags: c, linux, openwrt

I am able to get the IPv4 address of a given interface with following code

```
int fd;
char ipv4[33];
char ifname[] = "eth0";
struct ifreq ifr;

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname, IFNAMSIZ-1);
ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
close(fd);

snprintf(ipv4, 33, "%s", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));
```

What is the easiest way to get the IPv6 address of a given interface, using C ?

*** I AM POSTING THE CODE WHICH I COULD USE TO MAKE IT BELOW ..

```
int8_t find_device_ipv6(const char *ifname, char *ipv6, int8_t ipv6_size)
{
    FILE *f;
    int ret, scope, prefix;
    unsigned char _ipv6[16];
    char dname[IFNAMSIZ];
    char address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char *scopestr;

    f = fopen("/proc/net/if_inet6", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    while (19 == fscanf(f,
                        " %2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx %*x %x %x %*x %s",
                        &_ipv6[0],
                        &_ipv6[1],
                        &_ipv6[2],
                        &_ipv6[3],
                        &_ipv6[4],
                        &_ipv6[5],
                        &_ipv6[6],
                        &_ipv6[7],
                        &_ipv6[8],
                        &_ipv6[9],
                        &_ipv6[10],
                        &_ipv6[11],
                        &_ipv6[12],
                        &_ipv6[13],
                        &_ipv6[14],
                        &_ipv6[15],
                        &prefix,
                        &scope,
                        dname)) {
        if (strcmp(ifname, dname) != 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, _ipv6, address, sizeof(address)) == NULL) {
            continue;
        }
        snprintf(ipv6, ipv6_size, "%s", address);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is operating system specific. Sockets or network interfaces do not exist in standard C. You probably want to add a `Posix` or `Linux` tag

Comment: It is on OpenWRT platform, based on Linux.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743709/get-ipv6-addresses-in-linux-using-ioctl

Comment: Do you really need the v6-address(es) of a specific interface or will the primary address of the system do? (e.g. the address, which is used for outgoing connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your OS is Linux.

To find out how it is done, try `strace ifconfig eth0`.

You see that it is using `/proc/net/if_inet6` and some ioctl, notably `SIOCGIFADDR`

As [Ctx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5636775/ctx) commented, you probably want [getifaddrs(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)

Comment: The problem with strace is, that the solution is often quite low-level (since it shows only the calls through the kernel interface), where a cleaner (and more version-stable) might exist in userland. In this case for example `getifaddrs()` should be preferred whenever possible.

Comment: I can see it is getting through that proc file. The value in proc file is `fe80000000000000228984fffea6c63d` while my ip6 is `fe80::2289:84ff:fea6:c63d`. Do you know how to convert it?

Comment: I could do it with your idea. Thanks. I will post the code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is definitely using *getifaddrs()*, in case your glibc supports it.

If it doesn't you better don't want to know.....